# MySQL/PHP Insert and Update with Prepared Statements without "On Duplicate Record Update"

Tags: php, mysql

Once again something that seems like it should be simple turns out not to be so. I want to insert and update records using prepared statements because of the security they offer.   MySQL states “In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.” While the queries below do not show multiple tables,  once I get this working I will add detail tables (line items) to the data model.  Correct me if I am wrong but that indicates multiple unique indexes to me.  (The key on the master table would be order_num and the index on the line item table would be order_num and  line_num).
So to be able to easily insert and update tables I came up with the following scenario that does not use “on duplicate key update”.  The first query is INSERT IGNORE which will insert a new order number if it is not already in the table and not do anything if the order number  is already in the table.  Then I run an update query which in the first case will add the values for the rest of the fields and in the second case update the fields.
The problem is that only the first query will run. The second query always gives the following error.  Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Sites…  on line 207 Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\Sites… . It does not matter which query I run first, the insert or update (if I run the update first I update an existing field obviously).  The second query always fails.  It seems like some sort of table locking issue but the same error occurs even with a sleep statement of 3 seconds in between running the queries.  I am stumped.
A secondary issue is that having to prepare the statement for each field inserted into the table is not very elegant but it works.  If there’s a better way (that is simple!) I would love to know about it.  Thanks in advance to anyone who can offer some direction.

```
function insert($arr){
    if(!$mysqli_1=MyDatabase::getConnection()):
        echo 'Cannot connect to database.'. mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    endif;  
if($arr):
$cols=array_keys($arr);
$table_key_field_name=$cols[0];
$key_field_value=$arr[$table_key_field_name];
 $stmt_1 = $mysqli_1 -> prepare("INSERT IGNORE pi_hft_test_ajax ($table_key_field_name) VALUES(?) ");
 $stmt_1->bind_param("s", $key_field_value);//this binds the variables to the paramters (?) above, NOT the values;
 $stmt_1->execute();
endif; 
echo ' number of affected rows is '.$stmt_1->affected_rows.'<br />';
$stmt_1 -> close();
 $err = $mysqli_1->sqlstate;
 $mysqli_1 -> close();
}

function update($arr){
    if(!$mysqli=MyDatabase::getConnection()):
        echo 'Cannot connect to database.'. mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    endif;

if($arr):
    $part=$arr['part']; 
    $cols=array_keys($arr); 
    foreach($arr as $key=> $value):
        $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("UPDATE pi_hft_test_ajax SET $key=? WHERE part=? ");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $value, $part);//this binds the variables to the paramters (?) above, NOT the values;
        $stmt->execute();
    endforeach;
endif;  
$stmt -> close();
 echo '$mysqli->error is '.$mysqli->error.'<br />';
 echo 'SQLState is '. $mysqli->sqlstate;
 $mysqli -> close();
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem protected from injection to me.

Comment: You're trying to doing a bind operation on a statement that doesn't exist. E.g. your prepare call has failed, but your code simply assumed success.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not sure why you are saying the statement does not exist.  Each function (each query) runs fine on it's own and does update the table.  It's only when I run one query and then the other that the second query fails. Whichever query is run second always fails regardless of which one it is.